# How do I make my input choose what "Employee" I want to get information about?

Tags: python, function, class

I am new to programming and just about learning how to use classes. The first task I've chosen to do with classes is to make a "database" of employees in some firm.

My problem is that I want to make an input() function/variable that decides what employee I want to get info from.

My code looks like this:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, job, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.salary = salary

    def print_job(self):
        print(self.job)

    def print_salary(self):
        print(self.salary)

    def print_all(self, info):
        if info == "job":
            print(self.job)
        elif info == "salary":
            print(self.salary)
        elif info == "all":
            print("Name: " + self.name)
            print("Job: " + self.job)
            print("Salary: " + self.salary)


August = Employee("A.V. Fornitz Lyngstrand", "CEO", "50%" )
Rasmus = Employee("Rasmus F. Preisler", "Co. Founder", "50%")
Helle = Employee("Helle Rasmussen", "Investor", "0%")

emp = input("Who are you searching for? ")
print("Searching for", emp + "...")
info = input("What do you want to know?")


August.print_all(info)
```

I've made an input called "emp" and then I've tried to say

```
emp.print_all(info)
```

but it doesn't print anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am running it in VSCode and it says python 3.64 at my debugger so I guess it is python3. 

@Matthew I mean the parameters i have to pass into my employee.print_info() function. I have to write "all" if I want to see all info instead of all as I would like it to be. Is there no way to change that?

Comment: If I use raw_input() I get this error: 
severity: 'Error'
message: 'E0602:Undefined variable 'raw_input''
at: '36,8'
source: 'pylint'
code: 'E0602'

@jonrsharpe

Comment: What should I do then? I am running it in VScode. At the bottom it says. Python 3.6.4 and MagicPython. So are they different?

Comment: @Aran-Fey  I actually don't know what happen but suddenly I could just input the 'all' without quotation marks. I was just checking my extensions and all of a sudden it worked.

Right now my only problem is that I want to make a new input that decides what employee I want to see the data for.

Comment: That's a different question, but the short answer is: Put all the employees in a dict.

Comment: Thx, can you have more values assigned to one person?